# Pushing Laravel 5.2 app to Heroku, all files in public/ are missing

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application deployed on Heroku. However, all files that are in 'public' folder of my application are not loaded.

That is, no css and / or js are loaded pages after deployment. Only HTML is loaded.

This is the structure of my 'public' folder:

[image: This is the structure of my 'public' folder]

I'm loading the css that way:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And JS that way:

```
{!! Html::script('js/parsley.min.js') !!}
```

**EDIT**

I've figured out what was wrong.

Instead of loading the css the way I was doing, I should do this:

```
    <link href="{{ asset('css/parsley.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And for Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/parsley.min.js') }}></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange.

Are you sure that the files exist in the public folder?

Laravel 5.2 does not include html helpers function out the box, do you update your composer?

You can remove helper function and try without it, just use...

for css

```
 <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and js

```
   <script src="/js/parsley.min.js"></script>
```

if everything is ok, the problem is in your helper functions.

Comment: Yep, i'm sure.I've changed, but still the same problem

Comment: Ок, what you see in the network tab of your browser?
Which server response for these files?
Also you can load bootstrap files from cdn [link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7)